# High Charts stack column seperated in Three y Axis shows Data Labels incorrect position

Tags: highcharts

In HighStocks Stack Column Separated in Three Y-Axis, when tried to show their labels they show incorrect position. They are show at single position. Any Solution to show their stack labels top of the columns

Comment: You should post your code or code snippet.

Comment: Please recreate your example in jsfiddle.net